# Issue with connection to MSSQL from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm having problems putting data into MSSQL with PHP - I get this error:

> sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in [path] on line 13

I can't really see where the problem is, or if I have a syntax error.

```
<?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1"; 
    $dbusername = "humid"; 
    $dbpassword = "humid";  
    $db = "test";
    $t = $_GET['t'];
    $h = $_GET['h'];


    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db) or die("Couldnt connect to server");
    $dbconnect = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO historic VALUES(NULL,$t,$h,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    sqlsrv_query($dbconnect, $sql);
?>
```

ANY help would be greatly appreciated! I'm not familiar with MSSQL, only MySQL

---

Okay, now I've enabled error messages, and I've got this one now:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 126 [code] => 126 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid pseudocolumn "$t". [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid pseudocolumn "$t". ) )

However, I have no idea what that could be? Is it because $t is a SQL syntax that I don't know of? Long story short, I'm building a temp and humid logging device from an Arduino, and I need it to post the values into a DB (using PHP) - the syntax for the PHP looks like this:

> test.php?t=1&h=2

What have i done wrong now? When testing it on my MySQL server private, it all worked fine >_<

-- edit, solution found! --

Okay, I found the solution, I'm not sure if any of the other answers had a direct fix, however. MSSQL apparently doesn't accept "NULL" like MySQL does. But that was ofc. the last thing i edited, so I'm not sure if there were any errors in the prior code. Hoever, below is the final (and working) code. Arduino posts and everything. Eureka!

```
<?php
    $host = "WDKTO560\TEST"; 
    $dbusername = "humid"; 
    $dbpassword = "humid";  
    $db = "test";
    $t = $_GET['t'];
    $h = $_GET['h'];



    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $dbusername, "PWD" => $dbpassword, "Database" => $db) or die("Couldnt connect to server");
    $dbconnect = sqlsrv_connect($host, $connectionInfo);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO historic (temperature, humidity, date) VALUES($t,$h,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    sqlsrv_query($dbconnect, $sql) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple, it was a syntax error. 
MSSQL does NOT accept NULL to af inserted, but MySQL does. 
I wasn't familiar with MSSQL, so thats why I didn't saw the error.

So, the correct syntax for that line is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO historic (temperature, humidity, date) VALUES($t,$h,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

I simply had to specify the columns (the first table was ID, auto incremented) and remove the NULL. In MySQL NULL would skip that column.

Answer (score 0):

sqlsrv_connect() is failing to get a connection and returning FALSE. 
You will have to debug it.

1. Check if database and Username is correct .
2. User has access permission to write into DATABASE
3. You have installed the MSSQL driver for PHP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just double checked - seems like the user is right, and all permissions are set. I'll try using ODBC instead in a test.

Answer (score 0):

Connect using Windows Authentication.

```
<?php
    $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName,instanceName


    $ConInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $ConInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    ?>
```

Connect by user name and password.

```
 <?php
    $serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress";
    $ConInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UserId"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $ConInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Using user and password: Connection could not be established.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -1 [code] => -1 [2] => Invalid option UserId was passed to sqlsrv_connect. [message] => Invalid option UserId was passed to sqlsrv_connect. ) )